# How to multiple values of keys with different numbers in dictionary?

Tags: python

Im trying to multiple some values from dictionary

```
example
price_list = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 10}
```

when i type

```
total=sum(price_list.values())
print("Total sum is ",total)
```

it result 20
But now i want to multiple a with 3, b with 5, c with 2 and d with 3 and my desired output to be 59. What is easiest way to do that?

Comment: So you want `'aaabbbbbccddd'`?

Comment: You want to multiply key by a value?

Comment: no i want values of key to be multiply with number. I want value of a wich is 3 to multiply by 3 to get 9, value of b wich is 2 to multiply with 5 to get 10 etc.

Comment: Do you know how to access values by their key? What have you tried to solve this?

Comment: Do you have another list like `[3,5,2,3]` and you want to multiply each element of this list with the corresponding value in the dictionary?

Comment: Do you understand how did you get 20 as result?

Comment: Where those numbers come from ? 3 5 2 3 ?

Comment: yes, i get it with sum. But when i want to change values of a b c d with multiplying them with number( value of a wich is 3 to multiply with 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your numbers are stored in the list, iterate through the values, and multiply with your required number like so

```
price_dict = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 10}
numbers_dict = {'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}

result = 0
for key, value in price_dict.items():
    result += numbers_dict[key] * value
print(result)
#59
```

Comment: Dictionary order is only guaranteed in Python 3.7+, so you'd need to make `numbers` into a dict and iterate through by key in earlier versions.

Comment: Good idea. Fixed!

Comment: Using `sum` (updated): `result = sum(numbers_dict[key] * value for key, value in price_dict.items())`

Answer (score 1):

You can just perform operations on the dictionary item like you would any other variable:

```
# multiply 'a' by 3
price_list['a'] *= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
price_list = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 10} 
numbers = [3,5,2,3] 

for k,n in list(zip(price_list, numbers)): 
    price_list[k] *= n
```

then the price list will change, you can use `sum` as you did to calculate the result.